# TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentId' of undefined

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, odoo

The code of XML File-

```xml
<searchpanel class="gwssb_file">
  <field name="parent_directory" icon="fa-folder"/>
  <field icon="fa-folder" name="directory" domain="[['parent_directory', '=', parent_directory]]" select="multi"/> 
  <field groupby="category" icon="fa-tag" name="tags" select="multi"/>
</searchpanel>
```

Traceback:

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'parentId' of undefined
            at Class._getAncestorValueIds (http://localhost:8069/web/content/11479-1cd23a1/web.assets_backend.js:1625:324)
            at Class._getAncestorValueIds (http://localhost:8069/web/content/11479-1cd23a1/web.assets_backend.js:1626:79)
            at Class._getAncestorValueIds (http://localhost:8069/web/content/11479-1cd23a1/web.assets_backend.js:1626:79)
            at Class._createCategoryTree (http://localhost:8069/web/content/11479-1cd23a1/web.assets_backend.js:1614:810)
            at http://localhost:8069/web/content/11479-1cd23a1/web.assets_backend.js:1618:50
            at async Promise.all (index 0)
            at async Promise.all (index 0)
            at async Class._createSearchPanel (http://localhost:8069/web/content/11479-1cd23a1/web.assets_backend.js:1075:1139)
            at async Promise.all (index 1)
```

Hi Everyone, I get this error in the Odoo while making searchpanel in ODOO13. When I run the server. Sometimes it shows the searchpanel without error(login from different users). But after 4-5 logins. It suddenly throws this js. I know it is showing parentID is undefined. But as I do console.log(ParentID). It gives me the output. But the error is still there. I think I am doing it all right. Please help me out if someone faces this kind of error. For Example, The ParentID is shown that is 30. But still, it is throwing error.

```
the output is from js- childrenIds: []
display_name: "TSC00003"
folded: true
id: 32
parentId: 30
parent_directory: Array(2)
0: 30
1: "Vinod Rawat"
```

Comment: Please provide more code.

Comment: Here is the XML FIle- SearchPanel definition.

<searchpanel class="gwssb_file">     
     <field name="parent_directory" icon="fa-folder"/>
     <field icon="fa-folder" name="directory" domain="[['parent_directory', '=', parent_directory]]" select="multi"/>
     <field groupby="category" icon="fa-tag" name="tags" select="multi"/>
    </searchpanel>

@codemax

Comment: @rahulrawat, add the code in question by editing the question

Comment: @RohitAmbre, Please check once. Let me know if you need more details.

Comment: @rahulrawat I guess you need to provide the whole .js file. in addition, please provide the traceback under `debug=assets` mode. this would help us both to identify the problem.

Comment: @kerbrose, Thanks for your response. I haven't used any JS File. The error is coming from Addons part of Searchpanel.JS File IN ODOO13.